# Dialogflow: check if user send X messages in a row

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

Ok, I want to check if user sends 3+ messages in a row. If user send first message: do nothing, if send another one: do nothing, if send third: answer something.

I tried with Contexts but no luck.

```
var number = agent.context.get("repeat")["parameters"]["number"]
if (number == undefined) {
number = 1;
agent.context.set({
          name:'repeat',
          lifespan: 1,
          parameters:{
            'number':1
            }
        });
} else {
if (number < 3) {
number++
agent.context.set({
          name:'repeat',
          lifespan: 1,
          parameters:{
            'number':number
            }
        });
} else {
// SEND MESSAGE
}
}
```

I am getting this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'parameters' of undefined

Edit: I am using "dialogflow-fulfillment" library for Messenger chatbot.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/save-data#df_nodejs

Comment: I think that is available only for "actions-on-google", not for Messenger chatbot that uses "dialogflow-fulfillment" library. I tried anyway and I am getting this error "Cannot set property 'count' of undefined"

Comment: you can use this method, `const conv = agent.conv();` to get conv

Comment: No, it doesn't work, same error.

Comment: error you are getting because you are not getting those in parameter, please try to debug